# TripleDES encryption in c# and php is not same

Tags: c#, php, encryption, interop, cryptography

PHP code

```
define('SECRET', 'Your key here');
$data = 'test';

$enc = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, SECRET, $data, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, '12345678');

$url .= urlencode($password);
```

C# code

```
byte[] key = ec.GetBytes("Your key here");
byte[] iv = ec.GetBytes("12345678");
byte[] data = ec.GetBytes("test");
byte[] enc = new byte[0];
TripleDES tdes = TripleDES.Create();
tdes.IV = iv;
tdes.Key = key;
tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
ICryptoTransform ict = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
enc = ict.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

string szEnc = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(
    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(enc)
    );
```

My problem: The value of $url in PHP and szEnc in c# is not same.

Question: what wrong in my c# code?

Comment: `/` in the C# code, `8` in the PHP code. Please copy and paste your code when asking questions here, rather than re-typing it.

Comment: sorry my typing mistake. but my problem is not solved

Comment: Now you've left out the `8` completely. _PLEASE_ do not re-type. Copy. And. Paste. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TripleDES Encrypting in C# and PHP not coming out the same (PKCS7, ECB)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695414/tripledes-encrypting-in-c-sharp-and-php-not-coming-out-the-same-pkcs7-ecb)

Comment: sorry again, because my code contain real data so i must re-type data in my question.

Comment: Just use find and replace to edit out your data

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things can go wrong - but I've seen quite a lot of encoding (i.e. non cryptographic) issue when dealing with `string` and `byte[]`.

Never assume they will convert into anything, including ASCII.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(enc)
```

If you have unprintable characters, NUL... then this will **not** be part of the returned string and won't be url-encoded. This is ask true for PHP but it does not means it follows the same rule in every case.

Also I can't tell you what code like:

```
ec.GetBytes("Your key here");
```

will do ?!? If you're using an Unicode encoder then it won't give you the same as an ASCII encoder.

Beside encoding also check that the `PaddingMode` you use match the one used by PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use 1252 encoding instead of ASCII and my problems solved. Thanks for any answer.