# TripleDES encription not getting same results in c# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, mcrypt, tripledes

C# returns the following base64 encoded string:

```
joxzS5XnP63ymrhy6t4ogWK9TxwfwD83
```

below is the code in c#

us

```
ing System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Read in every line in the file.
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
        {
            string abc = "string to encrypt";
            Program p = new Program();
            string value =    p.Encrypt(abc, true);
            Console.Write(value);
        }
    }

    public string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
        {
            byte[] keyArray;
            byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

            //System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
            // Get the key from config file
            string key = "encrypt key";
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
            if (useHashing)
            {
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                hashmd5.Clear();
            }
            else
                keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            tdes.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }


}
```

I am using MCrypt library in PHP which returns

```
ThPKJ1BPJLeUwJtIT/zAs3ocZ2s6SU+M
```

PHP code:

```
$str = "string to encrypt";

$input = utf8_encode($str);
$key = "encrypt key";
echo apiEncode($input, $key);


function apiEncode($data, $secret)
{    
  //Generate a key from a hash
  $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);
  //Create init vector  
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ecb), MCRYPT_RAND); 

  //Pad for PKCS7
  $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
  $len = strlen($data);
  $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
  $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

  //Encrypt data
  $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb'); //, $iv);
  return base64_encode($encData);
}
```

apart from the above I have tried various other solutions found at so

[tripledes encryption not yielding same results in PHP and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467419/tripledes-encryption-not-yielding-same-results-in-php-and-c-sharp)

[TripleDES Encrypting in C# and PHP not coming out the same (PKCS7, ECB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695414/tripledes-encrypting-in-c-sharp-and-php-not-coming-out-the-same-pkcs7-ecb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Considering the Security vulnerabilities of DES and TripleDES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554526/comparison-of-des-triple-des-aes-blowfish-encryption-for-data), implemented AES/RIJNDAEL_256 algo at both the sides.

C#

```
    public String DecryptRJ256(string cypher, string KeyString, string IVString)
    {
        string sRet = string.Empty;
        RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        byte[] decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(cypher);

        try
        {
            byte[] Key = encoding.GetBytes(KeyString);
            byte[] IV = encoding.GetBytes(IVString);

            rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rj.KeySize = 256;
            rj.BlockSize = 256;
            rj.Key = Key;
            rj.IV = IV;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(decbuff);

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                {
                    sRet = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            rj.Clear();
        }
        return sRet;
    }

public string Encrypt(string message, string KeyString, string IVString)
    {
        byte[] Key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);
        byte[] IV = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IVString);

        string encrypted = null;
        RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
        rj.BlockSize = 256;
        rj.Key = Key;
        rj.IV = IV;
        rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                {
                    sw.Write(message);
                    sw.Close();
                }
                cs.Close();
            }
            byte[] encoded = ms.ToArray();
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);

            ms.Close();
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A file error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            rj.Clear();
        }

        return encrypted;
    }
```

PHP

```
public function apiEncode($text, $key, $iv)
{
    // to append string with trailing characters as for PKCS7 padding scheme
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($text) % $block);
    $text .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return base64_encode($crypttext);
}

publc function apiDecode($text, $key, $iv){

    $text = base64_decode($text);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $crypttext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code does not set an IV, thus your IV will be a block of zeroes. I do not know PHP, but I strongly suspect that mcrypt_create_iv() creates a non-trivial IV.

Apart from that, you should consider CBC-mode instead of ECB-mode.

Comment: it doesn't effect if i remove IV statements from the php code.

Comment: The second link you provided states that mcrypt_encrypt() does not actually use 128-bit keys; but instead of returning an error it will pad the key with zeroes. The key you derive using md5() is exactly a 128-bit key. I'm not sure I like deriving keys using a hash function, but if you insist to do so, then extract 192-bit or 256-bits from a SHA-256 hash instead.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php you MUST use a 192-bit key for 3DES in mcrypt_encrypt(). 256-bit was me mixing 3-key 3DES with AES. Sorry.